# How to loop over list between index

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I want to loop over list with indexes, while looping I want for loop to consider both start index and last index, although it respect start index it does not respect last index. The code I am trying is this:

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in arr[4:8]:
        print(i)
```

Actual Result:

```
4
5
6
7
```

Desired Result:

```
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: `4:8` are four items. Why do you expect it to be five items?

Comment: This is how slices are defined in Python (for objects of the standard library). You have to add one to the end index.

Comment: The end index is not inclusive in list slices.

Comment: I could ask the other way around - why are you surprised that the end of the slice is at `7`, but not surprised that the start of the slice is at `4`? A slice `0:4` *must* stop at `3`, so that a slice `4:8` can start at `4` - otherwise the whole system does not make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a "strategic" `+ 1` because slicing in Python excludes the last element:

```
for i in arr[4:8 + 1]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python slicing end index is not inclusive.

For example

```
print(list(range(4,8))
#[4, 5, 6, 7]
#won't include 8
```

Most of the cases this is sufficient.

For for specific use case, you may need to add '1' to the index.

```
for i in arr[start_index:end_index+1]:
    print(i)
```